# recursive function bug skips the first element in array on the second run

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

i have this function that prints every letter from array.
here is a link to jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yaroslav_cherednikov/ypbuhmqv/71/

it works well on the first run but then skips the first element in array on the second run

```js
    var a = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "renault"];
var d = document.getElementById('out');
var c = document.getElementById("cursor"); 
window.count = 0;
window.word_count = 0;

setTimeout(function () {
    c.style.visibility = 'visible';
    function aLoop() {
        setTimeout(function () {
                if(window.count < a.length){
                    return lettersPrint(a[window.count]);
                }
        }, 50);
    }
    function lettersPrint(word) {
        if (window.word_count < word.length) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                d.innerHTML += word[window.word_count];
                window.word_count++;
                return lettersPrint(word);
            }, 100);
        }
        else if( window.count < (a.length - 1) ){
            setTimeout(function () {
            d.classList.add("selected");
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function () {
            window.count++;
            word_count = 0;
            d.classList.remove("selected");
            d.innerHTML = '';
            return aLoop();
                
            }, 2000);
        }
        else{
            window.count = 0; 
            aLoop();
        }
    }    
    aLoop();

}, 1000);
```

```css
.typer-txt {
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: #378bd8;
    display: inline-block;
}
#cursor {
    float: right;
    color: #b9b9b9;
    animation: pulse 0.5s infinite;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#out {
    display: inline;
}
.selected {
    background-color: #378bd8;
    color: white;
}
@-webkit-keyframes h1-slide-up {
    0%   {top:100px; opacity: 0;}
    100% {top:0px;     opacity: 1;} 
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="typer-txt remove" id="typer-txt"><span id="cursor">|</span><div id="out" class=""></div></div>
```

this is first time i deal with a recursive function so i might have messed something. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting the word count when you are on the last word. I've updated your code and refactored the highlight and erase portion into its own function

```
    var a = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "renault"];
    var d = document.getElementById('out');
    var c = document.getElementById("cursor"); 
    window.count = 0;
    window.word_count = 0;

        setTimeout(function () {
            c.style.visibility = 'visible';
            function aLoop() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                        debugger;
                     if(window.count < a.length){
                         return lettersPrint(a[window.count]);
                     }
                }, 50);
            }
            function highlightAndErase(winCount) {
               setTimeout(function () {
                    d.classList.add("selected");
                    }, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    window.count = winCount
                    word_count = 0;
                    d.classList.remove("selected");
                    d.innerHTML = '';
                    return aLoop();

                    }, 2000);

            }
            function lettersPrint(word) {
                // previously was being missed after the last word due to the word_count not being reset
                if (window.word_count < word.length) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        d.innerHTML += word[window.word_count];
                        window.word_count++;
                       return lettersPrint(word);
                    }, 100);
                }
                else if( window.count < (a.length - 1) ){
                   highlightAndErase(++window.count)
                }
                else{
                    // previously was not resetting the word_count var
                    highlightAndErase(0)
                }
            }    
            aLoop();

        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:
You need a window.word_count = 0 next to window.count = 0 at line 38.
I believe word_count at line 30 needs to be window.word_count.

This will fix the skipped array item, but will introduce a new problem, which I'm sure you'll notice. I'll leave solving that item up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to reset some things in the else clause:

```
    var a = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "renault"];
    var d = document.getElementById('out');
    var c = document.getElementById("cursor"); 
    window.count = 0;
    window.word_count = 0;

        setTimeout(function () {
            c.style.visibility = 'visible';
            function aLoop() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                     if(window.count < a.length){
                         return lettersPrint(a[window.count]);
                     }
                }, 50);
            }
            function lettersPrint(word) {
                if (window.word_count < word.length) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        d.innerHTML += word[window.word_count];
                        window.word_count++;
                       return lettersPrint(word);
                    }, 100);
                }
                else if( window.count < (a.length - 1) ){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    d.classList.add("selected");
                    }, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    window.count++;
                    word_count = 0;
                    d.classList.remove("selected");
                    d.innerHTML = '';
                    return aLoop();

                    }, 2000);
                }
                else{
                setTimeout(function () {
                    d.classList.add("selected");
                    }, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                  window.count = 0;
                   window.word_count = 0;
                   d.classList.remove("selected");
                   d.innerHTML = '';
                    aLoop();
                  }, 2000)

                }
            }    
            aLoop();

        }, 1000);
```

Try to separate things in functions to understand better what you are doing! Sometimes recursive things are kinda messy if you don't separate and name things